# Replace object id for related objects

Tags: django, django-orm

Given models

```
class Reference(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
    version = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    ...


class First(models.Model):
    special_reference = models.ForeignKey(Reference, related_name='first_references')
    ...

class Second(models.Model):
    not_special_reference = models.ForeignKey(Reference, related_name='second_references')
    ...

class Third(models.Model):
    very_special_reference = models.ForeignKey(Reference, related_name='third_references')
    ...


ref_v1 = Reference(name="Main Reference", version=1).save()
first = First(reference_id=ref_v1.id).save()
second = Second(reference_id=ref_v1.id).save()
third = Third(reference_id=ref_v1.id).save()
```

I don't know how many models can relate to reference. ForeignKeys and related names can be different.

Now I will create next version of reference.

`ref_v2 = Reference(name="Main Reference", version=2).save()`

I need that all created objects of First, Second and Third models related to `ref_v1` change relation to `ref_v2`.

I know, that I can get all related models of `Reference` through `_meta` like this `Reference._meta.related_objects`. But I can't figure out how can I dynamically get all related models and change value of ForeignKey to new one.

Comment: You could have a `Version` model with `ForeignKey` to `Reference`. That way `First`, `Second`, etc, are always linked to the same `Reference`. If they may be linked to different versions, you could have a `ManyToManyField` of `Reference` through `Version`.

Comment: I don't need to save link to the old `Reference`. I need that all models change link to new `Reference`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You apparently want all models to stay linked to "Main Reference", but change the version. Adding a `Version` model with ForeignKey to `Reference` would allow you to keep `First`, `Second`, etc, linked to the same `Reference` and just update the version. If that's all you want to do, or even if there are some more fields that you need to update, that seems better than going through all related objects whenever you change a reference.

That said, if you really want to do it that way, once you have `Reference._meta.related_objects` you can iterate over them, and then this should work:

```
for related_object in Reference._meta.related_objects:
    model = related_object.related_model
    field = related_object.field.name
    model.objects.filter(**{field: ref_v1}).update(**{field: ref_v2})
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I need.